# Unable to take control of RIP register

Tags: c, security, gdb, stack-overflow

I am currently following "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation", and I am stuck.

I am trying to fully understand the stack overflow vulnerability.

In the book, the process of overflowing is shown using a x86 architecture, I have a x64. After having worked out, almost, the differences (hence the registers usage), and following this guide (https://blog.techorganic.com/2015/04/10/64-bit-linux-stack-smashing-tutorial-part-1/), I attempted to exploit this program (written by me):

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
int vgetstr(char *);            //Undound Input                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

int main(){                                                                                                                                    
    char s[8];                                                                                                                            
    printf("Enter your username: ");                                                                                                      
    vgetstr(s);                                                                                                                           
    puts(s);                    //Internal Debug Line                                                                                                                        
    return 0;                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
int vgetstr(char *s){                                                                                                                         
    char *p, c;                                                                                                                           
    for(p = s; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; p++)                                                                                          
    *p = c;                                                                                                                       
    *p = '\0';                                                                                                                            
    return p - s;                                                                                                                 
}
```

I used GDB to understand where RSP and RBP were, hence locating the return address:

```
 (gdb) break 8                                                                                                                         
 Breakpoint 1 at 0x748: file playground.c, line 8.                                                                                     
 (gdb) break 10                                                                                                                        
 Breakpoint 2 at 0x765: file playground.c, line 10.                                                                                    
 (gdb) r                                                                                                                               
 Starting program: /home/wsllnx/Detached/vuln                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 Breakpoint 1, main () at playground.c:8                                                                                               
 8               printf("Enter your username: ");                                                                                      
(gdb) i r rsp rbp                                                                                                                     
rsp            0x7fffffffe430   0x7fffffffe430                                                                                        
rbp            0x7fffffffe440   0x7fffffffe440                                                                                        
(gdb) x/32wx $rsp-0x8                                                                                                                 
0x7fffffffe428: 0x55400610      0x00005555      0xffffe520      0x00007fff                                                            
0x7fffffffe438: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0x55400830      0x00005555                                                            
0x7fffffffe448: 0xf7a5a2e1      0x00007fff      0x00040000      0x00000000                                                            
0x7fffffffe458: 0xffffe528      0x00007fff      0xf7b9b508      0x00000001                                                            
0x7fffffffe468: 0x55400740      0x00005555      0x00000000      0x00000000                                                            
0x7fffffffe478: 0xc5c3b21f      0xc5b939fe      0x55400610      0x00005555                                                            
0x7fffffffe488: 0xffffe520      0x00007fff      0x00000000      0x00000000                                                            
0x7fffffffe498: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0x1d03b21f      0x90ec6c81                                                            
(gdb) x/w s                                                                                                                           
0x7fffffffe438: 0x00000000                                                                                                            
(gdb) c                                                                                                                               
Continuing.                                                                                                                           
Enter your username: Unknown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Breakpoint 2, main () at playground.c:10                                                                                              
10              puts(s);                                                                                                              
(gdb) x/32wx $rsp-0x8                                                                                                                 
0x7fffffffe428: 0x55400765      0x00005555      0xffffe520      0x00007fff                                                            
0x7fffffffe438: 0x6e6b6e55      0x006e776f      0x55400830      0x00005555                                                            
0x7fffffffe448: 0xf7a5a2e1      0x00007fff      0x00040000      0x00000000                                                            
0x7fffffffe458: 0xffffe528      0x00007fff      0xf7b9b508      0x00000001                                                            
0x7fffffffe468: 0x55400740      0x00005555      0x00000000      0x00000000                                                            
0x7fffffffe478: 0xc5c3b21f      0xc5b939fe      0x55400610      0x00005555                                                            
0x7fffffffe488: 0xffffe520      0x00007fff      0x00000000      0x00000000                                                            
0x7fffffffe498: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0x1d03b21f      0x90ec6c81
```

So, if I am correct, since `RBP` is at `0x7fffffffe440` (0x55400830), the return address must be after; probably at `0x7fffffffe448`. (This is part of my reasoning).

Then I used GDB-PEDA to see easily the behaviour of `RIP`, after calculating the offset (using pattern_create -> pattern_offset. Result: 15):

```
gdb-peda$ r                                                                                                                           
Starting program: /home/wsllnx/Detached/vuln                                                                                          
Enter your username: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                              
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                                                  
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]                                                      
RAX: 0x0                                                                                                                              
RBX: 0x0                                                                                                                              
RCX: 0x7ffff7b15970 (<__write_nocancel+7>:      cmp    rax,0xfffffffffffff001)                                                        
RDX: 0x7ffff7dd5760 --> 0x0                                                                                                           
RSI: 0x555555602010 ('A' <repeats 15 times>, 'X' <repeats 52 times>, "\n")                                                            
RDI: 0x0                                                                                                                              
RBP: 0x5841414141414141 ('AAAAAAAX')                                                                                                  
RSP: 0x7fffffffe448 ('X' <repeats 51 times>)                                                                                          
RIP: 0x555555400777 (<main+55>: ret)                                                                                                  
R8 : 0x7ffff7ff0440 (0x00007ffff7ff0440)                                                                                              
R9 : 0x7ffff7ff0440 (0x00007ffff7ff0440)                                                                                              
R10: 0x193                                                                                                                            
R11: 0x246                                                                                                                            
R12: 0x555555400610 (<_start>:  xor    ebp,ebp)                                                                                          
R13: 0x7fffffffe520 --> 0x1                                                                                                           
R14: 0x0                                                                                                                              
R15: 0x0                                                                                                                                
EFLAGS: 0x10202 (carry parity adjust zero sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)                                                     
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]                                                         
0x55555540076c <main+44>:    call   0x5555554005d0 <puts@plt>                                                                         
0x555555400771 <main+49>:    mov    eax,0x0                                                                                           
0x555555400776 <main+54>:    leave                                                                                                 
=> 0x555555400777 <main+55>:    ret                                                                                                      
0x555555400778 <vgetstr>:    push   rbp                                                                                               
0x555555400779 <vgetstr+1>:  mov    rbp,rsp                                                                                           
0x55555540077c <vgetstr+4>:  sub    rsp,0x20                                                                                            
0x555555400780 <vgetstr+8>:  mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rdi                                                                       
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]                                                      
0000| 0x7fffffffe448 ('X' <repeats 51 times>)                                                                                         
0008| 0x7fffffffe450 ('X' <repeats 43 times>)                                                                                         
0016| 0x7fffffffe458 ('X' <repeats 35 times>)                                                                                         
0024| 0x7fffffffe460 ('X' <repeats 27 times>)                                                                                         
0032| 0x7fffffffe468 ('X' <repeats 19 times>)                                                                                         
0040| 0x7fffffffe470 ('X' <repeats 11 times>)                                                                                         
0048| 0x7fffffffe478 --> 0xb54553eb00585858                                                                                           
0056| 0x7fffffffe480 --> 0x555555400610 (<_start>:      xor    ebp,ebp)                                                               
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]                                                      
Legend: code, data, rodata, value                                                                                                     
Stopped reason: SIGSEGV                                                                                                               
0x0000555555400777 in main () at playground.c:12                                                                                      
12      }
```

After all of that I still don't understand why `RIP` is not under my control. If I don't understand why this is happening, then I cannot even attempt to create a shellcode payload. I am also planning to learn the NOP sled technique next.

What am I doing wrong here, why can't I overtake the Instruction Pointer?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'll would like to share my experience on binary exploitation.
when I started learning binary exploitation, I practiced [picoGym](https://play.picoctf.org/practice) and continued from there. I did not write my own code and tried to exploit it like you did, because you run into problems like this one, and have nowhere to get your answers from (besides posting questions here of course). In contrast to wargames such as [picoGym](https://play.picoctf.org/practice), you can read a write-up if you've come to a dead end and understand how to solve the challenge and not get stuck. (which almost always answers the questions and struggles you had before).
Correct me if i'm wrong, but by learning the way you do it, makes you lose motivation to continue and eventually stop learning it.
But whatever, that's just my opinion.

**Anyway**, you can use `cyclic` from [pwntools](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/) to calculate the offset to
`RIP`.
**In your case**:

```
cyclic --length 8 100
```

`--length 8` means that every address is 8 bytes in memory (like `RIP`). default is 4 bytes.
`100` is the number of characters to generate.

After that, you can copy the pattern generated by `cyclic` and enter it for the username in gdb (like you did with the A's). Then let the program continue and find where it crashed (it will be the saved return address on the stack that you overridden).
Finally do a lookup with `cyclic` on that saved ret address to calculate the offset:

```
cyclic -n 8 -l 0x6161616161616163
```

`-n 8` same as `--length 8`
`-l 0x6161616161616163` means do a lookup on the value `0x6161616161616163` in the generated pattern (to find the offset)

**Note:** the value `0x6161616161616163` was the ret address when I compiled and ran the code that you posted on my machine - it should be the same on your machine.